# Mongoose update nested object - exception: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path '...'

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema definition:

```
mongoose.model('User', new Schema({
        provider_id: String,
        name: String,
        email: String,
        avatar: String,
        level: Number,
        score: Number,
        progress: {
             levels: { 'type' : Array , 'default' : [] }
        }
}))
```

And I have documents like this in the database

```
{
     "_id": "987765692e7687c6b123123",
     "provider_id": "1231231230324",
     "name": "Jas Mad",
     "email": "proba2@test.com",
     "avatar": "proba2.jpg",
     "level": 1,
     "score": 0,
     "progress": {
         "levels": [
              {
                 "_id": "576c888362024585bc5faab8",
                 "categories": [
                     {
                         "_id": "576c888362024585bc5faab9",
                         "questions": [
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faaba"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faabe"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faac2"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faac6"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faaca"}
                         ]
                     }, 
                     {
                         "_id": "576c888362024585bc5faace",
                         "questions": [
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faacf"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faad3"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faad7"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faadb"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faadf"}
                         ]
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ]
     },
     "__v": 0
 }
```

Given the parameters: userId, categoryId, questionId, optionId

What I want is to update the object in questions array that match {***"_id": questionId***} adding a property {"selectedOption":optionId}

someting like this:

```
var setQuestionAnswer = function (data)
{
    var promise = new Promise(
            function (resolve, reject) {
                if (!data.levelId ||
                        !data.categoryId ||
                        !data.questionId ||
                        !data.optionId ||
                        !data.userId)
                {
                    reject({status:401, message: "Bad Request"});
                }
                User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {
                        '_id': data.userId,
                        'progress.levels._id': data.levelId,
                        'progress.levels.categories._id': data.categoryId,
                        'progress.levels.categories.questions._id': data.questionId,
                        'progress.levels.$.categories.$.questions.$.selectedOption': {$exists: false}
                    },
                    {
                        $set: {"progress.levels.$.categories.$.questions.$.selectedOption":data.optionId}
                    },
                    {new:true},
                    function(err, user){
                        if(err)
                        {
                            reject(err);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            resolve(user);
                        }
                    });
            });
    return promise;
};
```

When I run this code bellow, I get an error from mongo:

```
exception: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'progress.levels.$.categories.$.questions.$.correct'
```

if I use the zero index instead of **$** like **"progress.levels.0.categories.0.questions.0.selectedOption"**, I can modify successfuly the first try, but then never works again. How can I use a wildcard like **$** to make this update works for every question in the array?

I'm trying to get the user document updated like this

```
    {
     "_id": "987765692e7687c6b123123",
     "provider_id": "1231231230324",
     "name": "Jas Mad",
     "email": "proba2@test.com",
     "avatar": "proba2.jpg",
     "level": 1,
     "score": 0,
     "progress": {
         "levels": [
              {
                 "_id": "576c888362024585bc5faab8",
                 "categories": [
                     {
                         "_id": "576c888362024585bc5faab9",
                         "questions": [
                             {
                                 "_id": "576c888362024585bc5faaba",
                                 "selectedOption":"12312312312312312312"
                             }, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faabe"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faac2"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faac6"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faaca"}
                         ]
                     }, 
                     {
                         "_id": "576c888362024585bc5faace",
                         "questions": [
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faacf"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faad3"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faad7"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faadb"}, 
                             {"_id": "576c888362024585bc5faadf"}
                         ]
                     }
                 ]
             }
         ]
     },
     "__v": 0
 }
```

Greetings and thanks.

Comment: If I use this format **progress.levels.0.categories.0.questions.$.selectedOption** it will always update only the first question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieved to resolve it whit this query

```
var setQuestionAnswer = function (data)
{
    var promise = new Promise(
            function (resolve, reject) {
                debug('setQuestionAnswer');
                if (!data.levelId ||
                        !data.categoryId ||
                        !data.questionId ||
                        !data.optionId ||
                        !data.userId)
                {
                    reject({status: 401, message: "Bad Request"});
                    return;
                }
                User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {
                        '_id': data.userId,
                        'progress.levels._id': data.levelId,
                        'progress.levels.categories._id': data.categoryId,
                        'progress.levels.categories.questions._id': data.questionId,
                        'progress.levels.categories.questions.selectedOption': { $exists:false }
                    },
                    {
                        $set:{ 'progress.levels.0.categories.0.questions.0.selectedOption': data.optionId }
                    })
                    .exec(function(err,user){
                        if (err)
                        {
                            reject(err);
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            resolve(user);
                        }
                    });
            });
    return promise;
};
```

The find conditions object:

```
{
    '_id': data.userId,
    'progress.levels._id': data.levelId,
    'progress.levels.categories._id': data.categoryId,
    'progress.levels.categories.questions._id': data.questionId,
    'progress.levels.categories.questions.selectedOption': { $exists:false }
}
```

Using the [dot-notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) filter the document in the database

The update object:

```
{
    $set:{ 'progress.levels.0.categories.0.questions.0.selectedOption': data.optionId }
}
```

As the query is expected to return only one document I used the zero index to access the desired nested object and add the selectedOption property